# how to get text of a disabled text box using selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc

How to get the text of the disabled textbox element using selenium RC. 
x
I have a textbox which is disabled/grayed out with some strings like 'abcd12345' and when I try to get the text of the element using gettext,getattribute,getvalue etc all the 3 returns only empty string.
Can you please help me to get the text of the disabled textbox element using selenium RC.

The below is the HTML code..

```
<input type="text" disabled="" value="abcd12345" id="ABC_ty6" class="redbus_book">
```

Comment: Please provide sample code. Also, Selenium RC has been deprecated for several YEARS now; consider moving up to Selenium WebDriver.